# Validation of user input for quality

Tags: php, javascript, regex, tinymce, validation

Taking Stackoverflow as an example, how can one one set out to eliminate bad questions from popping up? Questions that only contain:

1. Spaces
2. Gibberish
3. Repetitive characters
4. Combination of characters such as 'fsdgh' etc
5. Other combinations as explained in Jeff's [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72523/heuristics-for-detecting-a-bad-answer) on Meta.

If I want to do this in Javascript, is there a way to programmatically find such combinations of characters in a post? Jeff's [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72523/heuristics-for-detecting-a-bad-answer) on Meta explains some heuristics and patterns for such a system.

I understand that there might be other ways to combat this like user registration and rate-limiting etc, but purely from validation and UX viewpoint, how can we make it happen, either on server-side or client-side? It would be a great way to tell the good users that the system will not expect bad posts either way.

This can use a combination of RegExps and loops for example. We do not even have to deploy all the requirements and perhaps a subset would do just fine.

Comment: So are you talking about examining the actual text of the post verbatim to try and determine if it is "bad"?

Comment: Yes, and programmatically.

Comment: One advice: If you're worried about "bad" data please check server side as well. JavaScript validation is for user experience only. It's a nice quick respone to user input without doing a server lookup but in the end you can't rely on it as "bad" users can create a form and post whatever garbage they can come up with to your server without your JavaScript ever being invoked. It can even be done by accident by users that don't have Javascript turned on.

Comment: Sorry but why do you think it's called **regular** expressions ? 'fsdgh'isn't regular.

Comment: @HMR, that is correct. And that is why I requested help with either. Once I know how it can be done in Javascript for example, I can implement it on the server side as well. But it would be nice to let the user know that the system will not accept bad text either way.

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV, even if we can deploy a subset of the requirements, that would be fine as well. For example 1, 2, and 3?

Comment: @user To write a regular expression, you have to write down what do you want to match. Ok, the spaces are simple `\s{2,}` this will match 2 or more spaces. Now the problem is with the gibberish part and repetitive part. We have to write down what's considered "gibberish" ? But this is quite difficult, say for example `abcd` you might consider it gibberish, but in mathematics the user may use it for `The perimeter of the square abcd is 20m`. Obviously you don't want to flag this one. Repetitive characters is quite difficulte in regex without a loop (in my opinion).

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV, right, let me edit the question to explain it in a better way.

Comment: @user If you want to save some headache use [akismet](http://akismet.com/) API.

Comment: Thanks @HamZaDzCyberDeV, I do want to think about this problem and its potential solutions though. I have updated the question with Jeff's post on Meta that explains some of the heuristics and patterns that Stackoverflow looks for when calculating the quality of posts. Is there a way to create RegExps for even a subset of those?

Comment: @user I'm not sure, I've to take a look at it some time. I'm busy for the coming days. You may try to contact me later. (google my name and you'll find me, or check my profile).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Questions that only contain:
>
> 1. Spaces
> 2. Gibberish
> 3. Repetitive characters
> 4. Combination of characters such as 'fsdgh' etc

1. Get the text of the post, do a trim(); on it (remove the white space), if the size of the text is now zero, your post only contained spaces. It is bad.
2. Hard one, maybe search for common words and phrases like "the, of, if, it", if many are absent or all are absent, it might be bad.
3. I don't think there are any words in the English language that have more than two repeated characters in a row. So as you parse the text, remember what the last character you saw was, if the next character is the last character you saw, set a flag if the flag is set the the next character is the one you last saw, bad post.
4. Same idea as above but search for words that have lengths of characters but without vowels, do research figure out what words have the longest chains of non-vowels, if you ever find anything more, its a bad post.

Most of these are hard to do because as computer scientists know English, and pretty much any spoken language, is backaswards to anything a computer can understand easily or parse through easily.

As you pointed out the only good way to take care of these problems is mods, registration, etc.

Oops, didnt see you wanted to use Regex's... But still its hard to do from any standpoint. (I think)

Comment: Thanks so much! Your solution to number 2 is very logical. I have updated the question with Jeff's post on Meta that explains some of the heuristics and patterns that Stackoverflow looks for when calculating the quality of posts. Is there a way to create RegExps for even a subset of those?

Comment: I don't know the Regex rules, but if there is Regex representation for "[consonant][consonant][consonant]" it might be useful. Just find the set of rules you want the text to abide by, namely the most extreme cases of English(vacUUm, bOOKKEEper, floccinaucinihilipilification) All valid English words but have sequences that might show up as gibberish. -- For #2 also maybe look for "ocious", "logy", "ing", "ed" i.e. common endings might help just a little more.